# How i break or make NSMutableSubstrings from NSMutableString in objective-C in iphone?

Tags: iphone, nsstring

I m the beginner in iphone
Thanks for sending me answer....
I want to break following NSMutable string into substring

```
200,8,"7 Infinite Loop, Cupertino, CA 95014, USA"
```

I wanting only Cupertino and CA from above Mutable String.
can it is possible in iphone in objective-C
The above data is the mutable data, which is came from httprequest object.
I want to fetching the city and state name from above same kind og mutable strings.
please give me the solution it creating a lot of hedac for me.

Comment: it is possible the above string break from each comma arriving from the string?

Comment: click the check mark next to one of the answers

Comment: @Rajendra: Did you see the check marks below the vote counts of each answer? Click on it to accept that answer.

Comment: THANKS KENNYTM FOR GIVING ME BOUNTIFUL TIP REGARDING SUCH KING OF THING.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are all of the strings that you want to break apart in this format?

```
NSArray *myArray = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSString * strippedNumbers = [[myArray objectAtIndex:4] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfRegex:@"[^0-9]" withString:@""];
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", [myArray objectAtIndex:3], strippedNumbers];
```

Answer (score 2):

If this is CSV data, check out

http://www.macresearch.org/cocoa-scientists-part-xxvi-parsing-csv-data

Answer (score 1):

One method would be to split the string at commas and trim whitespace:

```
NSArray *substrings = [myString componentsSeparatedByString: @","];
NSCharacterSet *whitespace = [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet];
NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];
for ( NSString *str in substrings )
    [result addObject: [str stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet: whitespace]];
```